# c# mysql , организовать поиск по таблицам базы данных

Tags: c#, mysql

приложение winforms. через textbox нужно организовать поиск по 10 таблицам, поиск одной таблицы возвращает результат, но как сделать поиск через information_schema.tables по всем 10 таблицам, все 10 таблицы имеют одинаковые типы данных, называние полей так же одинаковые, только название таблицы разные. ниже выложил код

```
private void SearchTextbox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    string searchData = SearchTextbox.Text;
    con.Open();
    adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM sta WHERE name LIKE '" + searchData + "%' OR surname LIKE '" + searchData + "%' OR phone LIKE '" + searchData + "%' OR login LIKE '" + searchData + "%' OR dslam LIKE '" + searchData + "%' OR ip LIKE '" + searchData + "%' OR port LIKE'" + searchData + "%'", con);
    dt = new DataTable();
    adapter.Fill(dt);
    dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
    con.Close();
}
```

тип данных выглядит следующим образом

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если нужно вернуть список всех названий таблиц, а затем прогнать их через цикл, то можно сделать это так:

1. Организуем запрос вида `SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES` — он вытащит названия всех таблиц;
2. Пишем такой код:

   ```
   List<String> tablesData = new List<String>();
   string query = "SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES";
   using(SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, con))
   {
       using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
       {
           while (reader.Read())
           {
               // берём поля из таблицы-кандидата
               string[] fieldNames = Enumerable.Range(0, reader.FieldCount)
                                     .Select(reader.GetName)
                                     .ToArray();
               // требуемые поля в виде строк
               string[] neededfieldNames = { ... };
               if (neededfieldNames.SequenceEqual(fieldNames)) {
                   /*
                    если все поля совпадают, то эта одна из 10 таблиц,
                    и мы берём её в список для прогонки скрипта
                   */
                   tablesData.Add(reader.GetString(0));
               }
           }         
       }
   }
   ```

   Он выполнит данный запрос по всей БД, достанет названия таблиц из БД и сложит их в список `tablesData`.
3. Через `foreach` стучимся к каждой таблице и выполняем необходимые действия:

   ```
   foreach (var table in tablesData) {
       adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM " + table + " WHERE name LIKE '" + ...);
       // ненужная часть после вызова таблицы убрана, чтобы было удобнее
       // потом идут все дальнейшие действия
   }
   ```

UPD: Anton Schyrov указал, что могут быть и таблицы, имеющие другую структуру => код может сломаться. Добавил проверку на то, что таблица имеет такие же имена атрибутов, как и одна из 10 требуемых (через [`SequenceEqual`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.sequenceequal?view=net-6.0)).

Comment: благодарю , попробую !

Comment: А потом у него в базе появляется таблица другой структуры и все идет лесом

Comment: @AntonShchyrov я понимаю, что данный метод работает только при том случае, если все таблицы одинаковы (как он сам написал). Вопрос был в том, как при текущей структуре организовать взятие названий таблиц; будь там какая-либо другая таблица с хотя бы одной отсутствующей строкой из скрипта, SQL бы послал

Comment: интересно, а в больших проектах с огромными таблицами как организовывается поиск данных ?

Comment: @4500zenja Он написал, что у него в базе 10 идентичных таблиц, а не что база состоит из идентичных таблиц

Comment: я вытащил таблицы только одной базы данных вот таким образом      `"SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = 'dslam'"`   так делать нельзя ?

Comment: @AntonShchyrov тьфу, думал, у него в БД только эти 10 таблиц и есть

Answer (score 0):

Есть два варианта решения:

1. Правильный. Привести в чувство структуру базы, эти 10 таблиц слить в одну и делать запрос к одной таблице
2. Как у вас. Занести названия всех таблиц в массив, а потом в цикле сделать запросы к каждой таблице

Comment: первый вариант,  суммировать в одну единую таблицу ?   если да, то для меня он не очень подходит, насчет второго варианты не могли бы выложить ссылки на примеры. т.к  пока не представляю как это сделать.

Comment: @Misterjunior первый вариант очень даже для вас подходит. Можете рассказать, какая нужда вас заставила заводить десять идентичных таблиц?

Comment: разъясните пожалуйста ,если не сложно

Comment: @Misterjunior  Можете рассказать, какая нужда вас заставила заводить десять идентичных таблиц?

Comment: первая причина управление таблицами, участникам не обязательно видеть все внесенные данные, каждому так сказать свое,  суммируется по разному,

Comment: @Misterjunior разграничение прав доступа делается при помощи view